# 2nd call to GetOpenFileName crashes without error on Win 8.1 64 bit machine

Tags: c, windows, 32bit-64bit

A personal project I'm working on is using [tinyfiledialogs](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyfiledialogs/) to help with some cross-platform gui stuff; this works great for the Unix systems I've tested on, however I've run up against a problem when testing on my Windows 8.1 64 bit machine.

The `GetOpenFileName()` function, when called from `tinyfiledialogs.c`, or from the below code, will execute correctly on the first call but crash shortly after the dialog window is presented on the second. However this *only* appears to be happening on my 64 bit machine - running the below code (or my code that uses `tinyfiledialogs.c`) on a Windows 7 32 bit machine works without issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void openD(){

char Filestring[1024] = "\0";
OPENFILENAME ofn={0};

ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
ofn.lpstrFile = Filestring;
ofn.nMaxFile = 1024;
ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT;

int retval = GetOpenFileName(&ofn);
if(retval == 1) printf("True!\n");
else {
    printf("value: %d\n", retval);
    int err_val = CommDlgExtendedError();
    switch(err_val){
        case CDERR_DIALOGFAILURE:   printf("ERR: CDERR_DIALOGFAILURE\n");   break;
        case CDERR_FINDRESFAILURE:  printf("CDERR_FINDRESFAILURE\n");       break;
        case CDERR_INITIALIZATION:  printf("CDERR_INITIALIZATION\n");       break;
        case CDERR_LOADRESFAILURE:  printf("CDERR_LOADRESFAILURE\n");       break;
        case CDERR_LOADSTRFAILURE:  printf("CDERR_LOADSTRFAILURE\n");       break;
        case CDERR_LOCKRESFAILURE:  printf("CDERR_LOCKRESFAILURE\n");       break;
        case CDERR_MEMALLOCFAILURE: printf("CDERR_MEMALLOCFAILURE\n");      break;
        case CDERR_MEMLOCKFAILURE:  printf("CDERR_MEMLOCKFAILURE\n");       break;
        case CDERR_NOHINSTANCE:     printf("CDERR_NOHINSTANCE\n");          break;
        case CDERR_NOHOOK:          printf("CDERR_NOHOOK\n");               break;
        case CDERR_NOTEMPLATE:      printf("CDERR_NOTEMPLATE\n");           break;
        case CDERR_STRUCTSIZE:      printf("CDERR_STRUCTSIZE\n");           break;
        case FNERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL:  printf("FNERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL\n");       break;
        case FNERR_INVALIDFILENAME: printf("FNERR_INVALIDFILENAME\n");      break;
        case FNERR_SUBCLASSFAILURE: printf("FNERR_SUBCLASSFAILURE\n");      break;
    }
}
}

int main()
{
openD();
openD();
}
```

The first call returns `TRUE`, the second fails to return and the program crashes. Attaching to a running instantiation of the program with the VS Express 2012 Debugger catches the following exceptions when the second call is made; first a popup:

`Unhandled exception at 0x759C36DC (shell32.dll) in ofd_64.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x70017AD8.`

Followed in Output by:

`First-chance exception at 0x759C36DC (shell32.dll) in ofd_64.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x70017AD8.
Unhandled exception at 0x759C36DC (shell32.dll) in ofd_64.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x70017AD8.`

Over multiple trials on the Windows 8.1 machine the exceptions have remained constant.

Curiously, if I remove the `OFN_EXPLORER` flag the process executes normally for both calls. This isn't a good solution though. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

The call stack from `VS Express 2012` shows:

```
shell32.dll!00007ffe6ef02777()  Unknown
shell32.dll!00007ffe6ebbf1c4()  Unknown
shell32.dll!00007ffe6ea5b5f3()  Unknown
shell32.dll!00007ffe6ea5b555()  Unknown
shell32.dll!00007ffe6ea5b493()  Unknown
shell32.dll!00007ffe6ea5b386()  Unknown
shell32.dll!00007ffe6eb07f02()  Unknown
shell32.dll!00007ffe6eb86d78()  Unknown
shell32.dll!00007ffe6e93bf9b()  Unknown
ExplorerFrame.dll!00007ffe5b912b30()    Unknown
ExplorerFrame.dll!00007ffe5b912abd()    Unknown
ExplorerFrame.dll!00007ffe5b8ff511()    Unknown
shell32.dll!00007ffe6e8043ed()  Unknown
shell32.dll!00007ffe6e813e1f()  Unknown
SHCore.dll!00007ffe6c30142f()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ffe71bab247()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ffe71bc8e15()    Unknown
kernel32.dll!00007ffe706b13d2() Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ffe71ba54e4()    Unknown
```

Comment: Did you still have the problem in you compile a 64bits code (the execution trace shows that you're using a 32bits code)

Comment: Is there a stack trace ?

Comment: According to MSDN comments, there is a bug that might explain what you get: "When using MFC compiled for multibyte-characters, you MUST set lpstrFileTitle to a valid pointer". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @purplepsycho Yes, the problem remains if I use the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt to compile

Comment: @Michael Walz I have updated my post with the call stack info from the VS Express Debugger

Comment: @Kuroi neko Having taken a look at that, explicitly setting `ofn.lpstrFileTitle = <some just initialized buffer>` does not solve the issue.

Comment: Ah well, that was worth a try :). Btw this call is deprecated since Vista, so as a last resort you might consider using the new-ish "Common Item Dialog" (which is another huge pain in the place where the sun does not shine to use, but hey, this is Windows we're talking about...)...

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't reproduce this problem on my machine (Windows 7 Pro Service Pack 1 64-bit). I compiled the above program using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition (targeting both Win32 and Win64) with no problems.

Comment: Are you building for UNICODE or ANSI?  Have you checked the address of the bad access against the variables in your code?  Is it an overrun in the file buffer?  (Perhaps because you said the length is 1024, and maybe the caller believed that was WCHARs rather than chars...)

Comment: I recommend searching the `OPENFILENAME` MSDN page for `OFN_EXPLORER` and `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT`.  There are several special behaviors linked to each of those options (and to both in combination).  Since removing of them makes a difference, I suspect there's a clue there.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested to me elsewhere, I tried calling `CoInitializeEx` prior to the `openD` function calls - this has solved the problem, though I can't say why. It doesn't seem to matter whether I use the `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED` or `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` flag, either works. Perhaps it's just some oddity in my particular machine.

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem of the Stack Size. Do not overwrite default Stack Size in VC++ 32 Bit Properties -> Linker -> System -> Stack Reserved Size. Let it empty. So the problem was solved on 64 Bit systems.